Brother printers print random characters and change the size of the printed pages
We have the following printers: 3x Brother MFC-L5750DW and 2x Brother HL-L6250DN. About three weeks ago, we started experiencing some issues with printing.
All of these Brother printers are having issues with two-sided printing. When I send a document to print, it starts printing the first few pages correctly, but then, at some point, it starts printing on only one side and changes the page size from A4 to something like A6 until the last page.
Example of issue with two-sided printing
With all of these Brother printers, whether printing single-sided or double-sided, they randomly print additional pages with random characters. These extra pages are added to the original print job, so everything prints correctly but with some extra pages containing random characters.
Example of issue with random characters 1
Example of issue with random characters 2
Users connect to these printers via shared printers on Windows server 2019 on DC server.

So first I tried update Windows server as usually, nothing.
I tried change connection from Windows PC directly to printer via lan network but nothing changed
I tried update firmware of Brother HL-L6250DN from 1.68, 1.63 to 1.82, 1.76 but nothing changed.

I figure out, that when I change behaviour of spooling ot printer from "Start printing immediately" to "Start printing after last page is spooled", the first issue with two-sided printing is fixed or happens only rare. On the second issue it did not have any effect.
Do you have any simillary experience from the last weeks? I do not know it occur. I think that it could break also some Windows update, antivirus (we have Bitdefender with Gravityzone management) or something else or device in network (maybe breaking some packets?)
This issue started occurring on all of our Brother printers. We also have many HP printers, but they don’t have any issues like this.

I figured out that the issue is probably caused by the WSD port. I changed the port to TCP/IP, and it works correctly now. So, it’s possible that a recent Windows update caused this problem.
